# javafx - Parent Positioning in Stage after scale incorrect

Tags: java, javafx

first what i do...
i scale a Parent-Object in its Controller...
ParentController.java

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
...
       if(scale != 1.0){
            //double oldWD = mainPane.getLayoutBounds().getMinX();
            mainPane.setScaleY((scale));
            mainPane.setScaleX((scale));
            mainPane.setLayoutX(-1*(stageWidth - (stageWidth*scale))/2);
            mainPane.setLayoutY(-1*(stageHeight - (stageHeight * scale))/2);
        }
...
}
```

And i the Application main i do...

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
...
           stage.setHeight(stageHeight * scale);
            stage.setWidth(stageWidth * scale);
...
}
```

**stageHeight** an **stageWidth** are default (double) values read from a config file.
widthout scale or scale 1.0 everthing works fine, but after scale the Root is not placed correctly in the Scene.

My Root is Setup from FXML like this:

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="mainPane" centerShape="false" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" stylesheets="@css/main.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="ParentController">
```

Answer (score 0):

found the issue, i have to use the Transform API, instead of

```
mainPane.setScaleY((scale));
mainPane.setScaleX((scale));
mainPane.setLayoutX(-1*(stageWidth - (stageWidth*scale))/2);
mainPane.setLayoutY(-1*(stageHeight - (stageHeight * scale))/2);
```

so

```
scene.getRoot().getTransforms().add(new Scale(scale, scale, 0.0, 0.0));
```

did the job.